# state change not prompting ondidchange

Tags: flutter, redux

I have a page which is connected to appstate and viewmodel ,

what i'm doing in this page is picking an image from gallery and then sending it to the server , when i send i prompt a message to the user so he can see the loading , 
when the upload epic ends there is an action than goes to the reducer which change the state so the ui in the page will change ,

the reducer receives it and return a state , but the onDidChange not prompt right after ,

here's some code:

page build method :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new StoreConnector<AppState, AddRefundViewModel>(
    converter: addRefundConverter,
    onInitialBuild: (AddRefundViewModel vm) => {vm.doInitializeDto()},
    builder: (context, vm) {
      return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Test',
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RefundHeader1(context, vm),
                      RefundHeader(context, vm),
                    ],
                  ),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.centerRight,
                        end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        colors: [primary, primaryGradient]),
                  ),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                ),
                //Text(vm.c),
                refundRowSum(vm),
                refundRowDate(context, vm),
                refundRowCurrent(context, vm),
                refundRowRefund(context, vm),
                refundRowAtm(context, vm),

                Expanded(child: Container(
                  child: GestureDetector(onTap: () {
                    //print("tap");}
                    // myFocusNode.dispose();},
                    if (myFocusNode != null) {
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                    }
                  }),
                )),
                proceedMessage(context, vm),
              ],
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
              child: proceedButton(context, vm),
            ),
            resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
          ));
    },

    onDidChange: (vm) {
      print('---!!!!-----<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  onDidChange  >>>>>>>>>>>-----!!!------');
      if (vm.addRefundDto.tmpFileStat == TmpFileStat.BadExt) {
        showSendReceiptDialog2(context, TmpFileStat.BadExt);
        vm.doInitTmpFileStat();
      } else if (vm.addRefundDto.tmpFileStat == TmpFileStat.TooLarge) {
        showSendReceiptDialog2(context, TmpFileStat.TooLarge);
        vm.doInitTmpFileStat();
      }
      else if (vm.addRefundDto.uploadRefundStatus ==
              RefundUpload.Success ||vm.addRefundDto.uploadRefundStatus ==
          RefundUpload.Started ||
          vm.addRefundDto.uploadRefundStatus == RefundUpload.Failed) {

        Navigator.pop(context);
        showSendReceiptDialog(context, vm.addRefundDto.uploadRefundStatus);
      }
    },


    );}
```

reducer :

```
  case GotRefund:
      print('----=== GotRefund add new refund reducer ===-----');
      AddRefundDto refundDto = state.refundDto;
      refundDto.uploadRefundStatus=RefundUpload.Success;
      state.refundDto= refundDto;
      return new AddRefundState(
        fileDto: null,
        byteImage: null,
        refundDto: state.refundDto,

  );
```

ADDED ViewModel :

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:iai/models/add_refund_dto.dart';
import 'package:iai/store/ui/ui_state.dart';
import 'package:iai/theme/images.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:iai/models/currency.dart';

class AddRefundViewModel {
  bool fileAttachment;

  DateTime pickedDate;
  double amount;

  bool isAtm;
  bool canProceed;
  AddRefundDto addRefundDto;

  //final List<String> refundList;
  final Map<String, AssetImage> refundList;
  final Map<String, IconData> currencyList;
  final List<Currency> currencyList2;
  Function saveCurrentViewModel;
  Function sendDtoToServer;
  Function openGallery;
  Function openCamera;
  Function doInitializeDto;
  Function doRemoveTmpImage;
  Function doInitTmpFileStat;
  final Function search;
  final String searchTerm;

  final bool showSearch;
  AddRefundViewModel({
    this.openCamera,
    this.openGallery,
    this.addRefundDto,
    this.search,
    this.searchTerm,
    this.showSearch,
    this.doInitializeDto,
    this.doRemoveTmpImage,
    this.doInitTmpFileStat,
    this.refundList,
    this.sendDtoToServer,
    this.saveCurrentViewModel,
    this.pickedDate,
    this.amount,
    this.currencyList,
    this.isAtm,
    this.canProceed,
    this.currencyList2,
    this.fileAttachment,
  });


}
```

thanks to everyone that can contribute

Answer (score 1):

Can you also post your AddRefundViewModel class in here? I think the on onDidChange is called based on those variables.

Comment: I added   the ViewModel ,   AddRefundDto addRefundDto;
is the field that is being changed on the state but not prompt here